# Cannot open file c#

Tags: c#

Can someone tell me why I have this error on the below code?

> The procces cannot access the file "..." beucase it's using by another procces.

I closed the first `StreamReader` and after, when I intialize the `StreamWriter`, it crashed.

```
private static void removeSetting(string _class)
{
    try
    {
        string[] allSettings = new string[20];
        int iSettings = 0;

        using (StreamReader FILE_READER = new StreamReader("DATA.properties"))
        {
            string line = FILE_READER.ReadLine();

            while (line != null)
            {
                if (!line.Equals(""))
                {
                    allSettings[iSettings] = line;
                    iSettings++;
                }
                line = FILE_READER.ReadLine();
            }
        }

        using (StreamWriter FILE_WRITER = new StreamWriter("DATA.properties", false))
        {
            for (int i = 0; i <= iSettings; i++)
            {
                if (!allSettings[i].Split('=')[0].Equals(_class))
                {
                    FILE_WRITER.WriteLine('\n' + allSettings[i] + '\n');
                    //i--;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }
}

public static void saveSetting(string _class, string value)
{
    removeSetting(_class);

    try
    {
        StreamWriter FILE_WRITER = new StreamWriter("DATA.properties", true);

        FILE_WRITER.WriteLine( _class.ToString() +'='+ value);
        FILE_WRITER.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you don't have the file open with a different process that has a write lock?  Maybe a text editor?

Comment: Also make sure you have permissions to the file.

Comment: I don't have any text editor opened.

Comment: My file is not a system/readonly/hidden file, it's... normal file.

Comment: Why are you calling `Dispose` manually if it's already in a using statement?

Comment: i just forgot to delete that xD sorry

Comment: Which line is failing? Also are you certain that DATA.properties is in the current working directory at the time you enter this function? Either use an absolute path or verify `Environment.CurrentDirectory` while the program is running.

Comment: At using (StreamWriter FILE_WRITER = new StreamWriter("DATA.properties", false)) blocks.

Comment: What's with the try/catch block in saveSetting?  I'm guessing you're calling saveSetting somewhere, it's generating an exception, and therefore not closing the stream.  There's no reason to call Close manually.  Just use a `using` block.

Comment: I have the same error.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solution: you need find a program which open this file and kill it or reload OS.

I suggest you want change "_class=oldValue" on "_class=newValue" by using _class like this

oldText:

dog=lock

cat=bob

use saveSetting(dog, fork)

newText:

cat=bob

dog=fork

you can use this method

```
private static void removeSetting(string _class,string value)
        {
            try
            {
                //read all lines from file
                string[] allSettings = File.ReadAllLines("DATA.properties");

                //divide string on string[] by '='
                List<List<string>> strings = allSettings.Select(x => x.Split(new char[] { '=' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList()).ToList();

                //find all lines where first element equals _class
                List<List<string>> result = strings.Where(x => x.First().Equals(_class)).Select(x=>new List<string>{_class, value}).ToList();

                // convert string[] => string
                string[] secondResult = result.Select(x => String.Join("=",x.ToArray())).ToArray();

                List<List<string>> otherResult = strings.Where(x => !x.First().Equals(_class)).Select(x => x).ToList();

                string[] firstResult = otherResult.Select(x => String.Join("=", x.ToArray())).ToArray();

                //wrtie all lines in file
                File.WriteAllLines("DATA.properties",firstResult);

                File.AppendAllLines("DATA.properties", secondResult);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
        }
```

Comment: My properties file has a unknown numbers of '=' on a line(bigger or equal then one) ex: user=Xg245=asFS5=43 (i crypt the text before to be written in the file).